# Linq Multiple join to 'Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported' Error

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a test my application using enitity framework, and ran into this error:

"Unable to create a constant value of type  Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

However, I can't think of a way around the problem?

```
var products = GeneralContext.Inventory
.Join(GeneralContext.Products,
    invtry => invtry.ProductId,
    prdct => prdct.ProductId,
   (invtry, prdct) => new { Inventory = invtry, Product = prdct })
.Where(q =>
    q.Inventory.PlaceId == (int)model.PlaceId &&
    q.Inventory.InventoryStatu == (int)Enums.Reason.Stok &&
    q.Product.IsWithRecipe == false &&
    boxes.Any(c=>c.Inventory.ProductCode == q.Inventory.ParentProductCode))
.ToList();
```

Comment: Get a list of the codes from `boxes` and use that instead.

Comment: boxes is another product list of new { Inventory = invtry, Product = prdct })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a collection of the codes you want to filter on up front and use that instead of a collection of a complex type.  You might need to do the same with the place id as well.

```
var codes = boxes.Select(c => c.Inventory.ProductCode).ToList();
int placeId = (int)model.PlaceId;

var products = GeneralContext.Inventory
.Join(GeneralContext.Products,
    invtry => invtry.ProductId,
    prdct => prdct.ProductId,
   (invtry, prdct) => new { Inventory = invtry, Product = prdct })
.Where(q =>
    q.Inventory.PlaceId == placeId &&
    q.Inventory.InventoryStatu == (int)Enums.Reason.Stok &&
    q.Product.IsWithRecipe == false &&
    codes.Contains(q.Inventory.ParentProductCode))
.ToList();
```

Basically EF is limited on what you can use because it's trying to translate the code into SQL and it cannot create SQL code to work on complex types.